# Extract specific text from drop down list

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, vba

I am looking to create a drop down list within Excel that shows detail on a `part index`, `title` and `number` but, once it has been selected, only shows the `part index` as text.

Below is an image that shows the a detailed drop down box (I want to keep the detail within the drop down):

[image: a detailed drop down box]

And here is an image that shows the drop down box with only the `part index` (I want to only show the `part index` once the part has been selected):

[image: drop down box with only the part index]

If anyone knows a way of doing this I would greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: It has been asked before the but the solutions do not work for me. However, I have discovered my own solution.

Comment: Answer is below

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by naming a table using the Name Manager function in the Forumlas tab.

I then referenced this Named Table in the data validation wizard by pressing F3 with my cursor in the Source bar.

From there I used the following code

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error Resume Next

Dim textVal As String
Dim strVal As String

    strVal = Target.Value
        If Target.Column = 2 Then
            textVal = Left(strVal, 8)
            Target.Value = textVal
        End If
End Sub
```

Where 2 in `Target.Column = 2` references column B in my worksheet and 8 in `textVal = Left(strVal, 8)` references the number of characters I want to display once the drop down list has been selected.

Ensure that you have formatted the column with the drop down list as text to stop excel from crashing and `On Error Resume Next` removes runtime error 13.